# Visual Studio installer - How to create registry key

Tags: registry, filepath

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects extension.  I am trying to create a simple installer as a learning project.  I have never done this before and apparently my awesome googling skills are failing me now.

I have a very simply WinForm project which has a couple of labels.  When the project starts up, I want it to read values from the registry and display the paths to two folders.  I am trying to create those keys and values during the install process.

Under HKCU\Software\MyProgram I want a key name 'Files', and a key name 'Media'.  I want the value for those keys to be the current users Documents folder, with a sub folder MyProgram, which will have two subfolders Files and Media. So basically the following:
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\MyProgram\Files
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\MyProgram\Media

The question is what do I put in the value to represent the '%USERPROFILE%\Documents' portion?  I intially thought it would be something like [Documents]\MyProgram\Files and [Documents]\MyProgram\Media but this apprently is not the case.  Or am I just going about this in a way that will simply not work at all?  What I end up with in the registry is \MyProgram\Media.

Comment: I don't understand the need to do this from your installer. When your app starts up, it checks to see if the registry values exist, and if not creates them. You can get the user's profile directory in code, so you don't need to worry about it in your installer.

Comment: I prefer to use the installer to establish the default values so the user has something to work with from the beginning.  They may then choose to change those values, for example they may was to use D:\Files and D:\Media, but I am not going to know that immediately.  So default values make sense.  I suppose I could revert to the good old days of .ini files and ignore the registry all together, but that seems to not be the current way to do things.

Comment: They'd still have something to work with from the beginning. *When your app starts up, it checks to see if the registry values exist, and if not creates them* means that your app creates them as needed the first time it runs, and then the values are there when your app finishes loading the first time, and already exist in the registry every subsequent run.

Comment: ..and the only way the program can check for and create them is if I write the code to make that happen.  I do not wish to do this as I do not want the program checking every time it starts.  I want it assumed that the values are in the registery and can be accessed when/if needed.  I have several programs on my machine that do indeed write paths to the registry before they are ever ran. I know this because I can see them.  I can do this if I have a fixed path such as c:\jsmith\documents\MyProgram\File, but not all computers will have the user name of jsmith.

Comment: You have to write the code to read the values anyway, and it would take less than a dozen additional lines to create them if they're not there. You'd have it written already in the time we've been commenting back and forth.

Comment: Thank you Ken however my question was how do I do something in a specific way.  I was not looking for 'alternative' ways to do it.  Clearly paths can be written dynamically during install and that is my preferred way.

Comment: OK. It's always good to  be set on a fixed goal, instead of being open to alternative suggestions. Good luck.